# np. where : compare the absolute value of a column

Tags: python, pandas

I am using np.where to calculate the amount of a column but need to analyse only abolute values without chaning a column itself.
Currently, I am using this code:`

```
dfv['Movement'] = np.where(dfv['Variance vs last December'].gt(2000000), 'Y','N')
```

Is there any way to include absolute in here?

Kind Regards

Comment: Use pandas Series [`abs`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.abs.html) before `.gt` like: `dfv['Variance vs last December'].abs().gt(2000000)`

Comment: Please explain why you are using `.gt(value)` construct rather than just `> value`

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
dfv['Movement'] = np.where(abs(dfv['Variance vs last December']).gt(2000000), 'Y','N')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Series.abs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.abs.html):

```
dfv['Movement'] = np.where(dfv['Variance vs last December'].abs().gt(2000000), 'Y','N')
```